# How can I do dataframe subtraction?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:
Col1 is the payment.

```
Col1     Value
Item1    100
Item2    200
Item3    300
```

and Col2 is the Project cost

```
Col2        Value
Project1    200
Project2    300
Project3    400
```

I basically want to match Col1 with the project in Col2.

How can I get the following dataframe?

```
Col2         Value    Col1 
Project1     100      Item1
Project1     100      Item2
Project2     100      Item2
Project2     200      Item3
Project3     100      Item3
Project3     300
```

Is there anything I can do in the pandas to get this result?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why is only `Item2` repeated?

Comment: Can you explain exact logic for final output?

Comment: @jezreal I want Col1 to match with Col2. First in Col2, Value of Project 1 is 200. Item1 in Col1 cannot fulfill the need (which is 100) so item2 is break into two part to pay for Project1.

Comment: @jezrael sorry that I miss that part. I have updated my expected result.

Comment: why is last `Item3` missing ?

Comment: @MohitSharma  I have updated my question. Sorry for the misleading.

Comment: @jezrael it is because Project3 required 400 but after subtraction, item3 only have 100 left. So there is a deficit of 300 for Project 3

Comment: @MohitSharma  Is it more clear for you to understand the final output logic? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here, you can find logic, comments are added for explaination:

```
# making list of project requirement and item value to iterate
item_cost = list(zip(payment['Col1'], payment['value']))
requirment = list(zip(project_cost['Col2'], project_cost['value']))

d = {}
for project, cost in requirment:
    item_used = []
    try:
        while cost > 0: 
            if item_cost[0][1] <= cost: # if item is having less cost than requirement
                cost -= item_cost[0][1] # making requirement less by item cost
                item_used.append((item_cost[0][1], item_cost[0][0]))
                item_cost = item_cost[1:] # removing item from item_cost once used
            else: 
                item_cost[0] = ((item_cost[0][0], item_cost[0][1] - cost))
                item_used.append((cost, item_cost[0][0]))
                cost = 0
    except: # when item list will be finished exception will be called
        item_used.append((cost,np.nan))
    d[project] = item_used
# d is dict having project as key and item used
project_cost['Col1'] = project_cost['Col2'].map(d)          
pr_cost = project_cost.explode("Col1")            
pr_cost['value'] = pr_cost['Col1'].apply(lambda x:x[0])            
pr_cost['Col1'] = pr_cost['Col1'].apply(lambda x:x[1])
```

sample output
[image]

As per your new data, we need to just change the column name to above code:

```
item_cost = list(zip(payment['Payment'], payment['Value']))
requirment = list(zip(project_cost['Project'], project_cost['Cost']))
d = {}
for project, cost in requirment:
    item_used = []
    try:
        while cost > 0: 
            if item_cost[0][1] <= cost: # if item is having less cost than requirement
                cost -= item_cost[0][1] # making requirement less by item cost
                item_used.append((item_cost[0][1], item_cost[0][0]))
                item_cost = item_cost[1:] # removing item from item_cost once used
            else: 
                item_cost[0] = ((item_cost[0][0], item_cost[0][1] - cost))
                item_used.append((cost, item_cost[0][0]))
                cost = 0
    except: # when item list will be finished exception will be called
        item_used.append((cost,np.nan))
    d[project] = item_used
project_cost['bank_val'] = project_cost['Project'].map(d)          
pr_cost = project_cost.explode("bank_val")            
pr_cost['value'] = pr_cost['bank_val'].apply(lambda x:x[0])            
pr_cost['bank'] = pr_cost['bank_val'].apply(lambda x:x[1]) 
print(pr_cost.drop(columns = ['bank_val', 'Cost']))
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, when I try to input other name in the Col2, the error come out: 

---> 20 pr_cost['Value'] = pr_cost['Col1'].apply(lambda x:x[0])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: payment = pd.DataFrame({'Payment':["BankA","BankB","BankC","BankD","BankE","BankA","BankC"],'Value':[1000,1000,600,400,1000,5000,700]})

Comment: project_cost = pd.DataFrame({'Project':["ProjectA","Project ZZZ","Food (20%)","AAA","BBBB","CCCCC","88","QWER"],'Cost':[857,3190,3810,2334,1465,44,153,516]})

Comment: I added these two dataframe. Please have a look. Also, their column is not the same. One is "Value" and other one is "Cost".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your kindly assistant is much appreciated. It exactly what I want. I have some confusion on the lambda function here. What .apply(lambda x:x[0]) actually do? I guess somehow it get the value and bank from x[0] and x[1] column, in this case which dataframe does this x refered to?

Comment: In for loop we are finding bank with value, and I am appending them as tuple with value and bank. you can check bank_val column.Also you can check dictionary d, which is having all information and can relate it with for loop block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208167/discussion-between-kevin-kwong-and-mohit-sharma).